# Create Face Mask from Original Image

Tags: android, canvas, face-detection, masking

In my case, I have an image which detects a face using face-detection. now I want to try to create a face mask of detected face but I have no idea how to create a face mask of detected faces.so please help me how can I create a face mask of the original image. In face detection, I can use google-vision to detect a face like an oval. I can use [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/face-detection-in-android-with-google-play-services/) to detect a face.

Thank you in advance.